# Laravel - how to show errors on terminal rather than log file?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, tdd

I'm watching [TDD by Example](https://laracasts.com/lessons/tdd-by-example) Laracast and I see whenever he runs `phpunit` and a **fatal error** or an **uncaught exception** is thrown, it gets logged in the terminal like this:

```
MyControllerTest::test_it_shows_create_form
InvalidArgumentException: View [mycontroller.create] not found
```

But whenever I run `phpunit` and get a fatal error or an uncaught exception, it just get logged directly to `storage/logs/laravel.log` instead of showing it in the terminal, which makes it harder and slower to do TDD.

Is there a configuration I might be missing that's causing me this issue?

**Edit:**

My console outputs this

```
MyControllerTest::test_it_shows_create_form
Failed to assert 200 equals 500
```

The failed assertion is a `$this->assertResponseOk()`, and since something is wrong (an uncaught exception maybe) http response code is 500.

But as you can see, it won't show me what the error is

Comment: Are you using homestead or are you developing locally in your computer?

Comment: I'm using homestead, but I'm running phpunit from my host machine. Although, even if I run it from homestead I still don't get those errors on console

Comment: Could you paste the content of your console after having an error?

Comment: @Romain Check out my edit, please

Answer (score 0):

Testing with PHPUnit, Behat, etc. runs your application in a different environment. So basically you should enable debugging for the environment that your test suite is using. If I recall correctly, test suites run your application in the `testing` environment. In that case you should create a `.env.testing` file in your root directory and enable debug option there.

Comment: I manually printed the value of APP_DEBUG and it's set to true